# Display the formula value of 2 textboxes in 3rd - Javascript

Tags: javascript

This the formula `[(min*30)+sec]/500`
Where `min` is textbox value 1 and `sec` is textbox value 2

```
Minutes<input type="text" value="" name="min">
Seconds<input type="text" value="" name="sec"><br>
 Output<input type="text" value="" name="output"><br>
  <input type="Button" value="Calculate" name="Calculate"><br>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
$(function(){
        $(".calculate").on("click", function(){
            var min = $(".min").val();
            var sec= $(".sec").val();
        var output =parseInt(parseInt(min)*parseInt(sec) / 500);
    });    
});
</script>
```

Comment: See: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something? Do you have any error?, perhaps you could show some javascript code.
Anyways, if you are not using jquery try something like this:

```
Minutes<input type="text" id="min" value="" name="min">
Seconds<input type="text" id="sec" value="" name="sec"><br>
Output<input type="text" id="output" value="" name="output"><br>
<input type="Button" value="" onclick="calculate()" name="Calculate"><br>
```

js:

```
function calculate() {
  var min = parseInt(document.querySelector('#min').value);
  var sec = parseInt(document.querySelector('#sec').value);
  document.querySelector('#output').value = [(min*30)+sec]/500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it is easy to solve.

```
Minutes<input type="text" value="" name="min" class="min">
Seconds<input type="text" value="" name="sec" class="sec"><br>
Output<input type="text" value="" name="output" class="output"><br>
<input type="Button" value="" name="Calculate" class="calculate"><br>
```

Try this, this may help you.

```
 $(function() {
   $(".calculate").on("click", function() {
     var min = $(".min").val();
     var sec = $(".sec").val();
     var output = parseFloat(((min*30) + sec) / 500);
     $(".output").val(output);
   });
 });
```

let me know.

Comment: I updated the code please check the question it doesnt show anything